# React TypeScript | Correct Type for Event Handler Prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

My App component passes down an event handler as a prop to a `Button Component`

```js
// App.js

  public handlePlay = () => {
    this.setState({ ****** })
  }
```

```js
// render

<Button play={this.handlePlay} />
```

What is the **correct type** for the event handler passed via prop i.e. `play`?

```js
// Button.js
interface ButtontProps {
  play: any //what is the correct type here?
}

export const Button: React.SFC<ButtontProps> = ({ play }) => (
  <button onClick={play}>Play</button>
)
```

I don't want to use `any` as that would divert me from applying the correct types for such an instance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use the `MouseEventHandler` type with `HTMLButtonElement` as the type parameter:

```
interface ButtonProps {
  play: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>
}
```

Answer (score 18):

It should most likely be either of the following

```
(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => void
(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void
```

You can confirm this by looking at the React typings [over here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/55dbfec2ebcae6de09f253f41c69b72adada3277/types/react/index.d.ts#L1222).

Comment: Thank you, Christian. Are you suggesting that inside the `handlePlay(event: ...)`?

Comment: For `play` in `ButtonProps` definitely. `handlePlay` can omit this if it doesn't use the event in the first place due to the nature of JavaScript allowing parameter omission.

Comment: I'm failing to translate your suggestion into my current code example in the question above. I added   `onClick={(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => playAgain}` but it errors `type is not assignable to intrinsic attributes`

Comment: @Jonca33 Do it as shown in the answer of Oblosys. It suffices to replace your `any` that you annotated in the first place with either of our solutions.

Answer (score 0):

**This should work also**

```
import { MouseEventHandler } from "react";

export interface ButtonProps{
    play: MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>
}

export const Button = ({ play }: ButtonProps ) => (
  <button onClick={play}>Play</button>
)
```